# How to validate if an element is present using protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, cucumber, assertion

I am trying to check if an element is present or not on a screen in Protractor-cucumber framework. I am using isPresent().toBe(true) to verify. But whenever I am trying to use toBe(true), I see the following error on the scree

Property 'toBe' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.ts(2339)

Below is my code:

```
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')
chai.use(chaiAsPromised)
var expect = chai.expect
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions
.
.
.
.
.

Then('I verify element X is available', function (callback) {
browser.waitForAngular()
.then(() => {expect(PageObject.X.isPresent()).toBe(true);})
.then(callback)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `expect` keyword from `jasmine`

```
# Global installation 
npm install -g jasmine

// Element exists.
expect(element(by.binding('person.name')).isPresent()).toBe(true);

// Element not present.
expect(element(by.binding('notPresent')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

or try to install chai using typedefinitions and then retry your code

```
npm install --save @types/chai
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!!I tried doing chai typedefinitions, but after installing I am seeing this error. Isee this error often whenever I do webdriver-manager update. Is there any fix for this?  
node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2824:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'xit' must be of type 'It', but here has type 'PendingTestFunction'.